# Conditional expectations of a stochastic process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $(X_t)_{t\geq0}$ be a stochastic process such that $X_t>0$, $X_t\to X_0>0$ pathwise, 
$\mathbb{P}(X_t>M)=o(\sqrt{t})$  for all $M>X_0$, and $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to 0}\mathbb{E}[X_t]<\infty$.

Then 
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[X_t\mathbb{1}\{X_t>M\}]=\mathbb{E}[X_t|X_t>M]\mathbb{P}(X_t>M)=o(\sqrt{t})
\end{equation}
assuming $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to0}\mathbb{E}[X_t|X_t>M]<\infty$, so the question is, are the assumptions sufficient to say that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{t\to0}\mathbb{E}[X_t|X_t>M]<\infty
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  Let $U \sim U(0,1)$, and let
$$X_t = \begin{cases} 1, &&  U \ge t \\
\frac{1}{t}, && U < t.
\end{cases}$$
Then $X_t \to 1$ almost surely as $t \to 0$, and for any $M > 1$ we have $\mathbb{P}(X_t > M) = t = o(\sqrt{t})$.  Moreover, $\mathbb{E}[X_t] = (1-t)+1 \to 2$.  But $\mathbb{E}[X_t \mid X_t > M] = 1/t \to \infty$.

Comment: Thanks. 

It seems to me that if $X_t$ was uniformly integrable, we would obtain this rate of convergence. 
Can you spot any weaker and sufficient condition than that?